# Emulate home network IP

Tags: vpn, proxy, ip

I wanted to use a service that would allow me to connect to my home network remotely that will emulate the home network IP on the remote computer. So once connected if I went to myip it would show the IP that I would have if I was in my network. I've read various things but don't have a definitive answer on what I should use whether it be a proxy, vpn, or another type of service. I was hoping that it would be a free service that doesn't have a restriction on bandwidth.

I have a media server computer that is always on that runs Windows 7 ultimate if I need a device to act as a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a VPN.  If you have a Windows Server on your LAN you could set up a PPTP connection, which is very easy to do, and connect you Windows laptop to it, which is also very easy.

If you do not have a Windows Server on your LAN you could use OpenVPN instead, which is more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can route  the whole of your traffic through your home server. This can be done via VPN or by running a web proxy on your home box. Now, because your home server runs Windows, I can not help further. I can say that OpenSSH server on all sort of Unixes gives you a SOCKSv5 proxy that putty can utilize (Connection->SSH->Tunnels destination localhost, click auto and dynamic, the port you give here will be your socks proxy port in firefox/chrome). Whether the SSH servers https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows listed here have that built in, I have no idea. Building a VPN connection is an even worse PITA so I won't divulge into that.